# Need to enter text through automation in a rich text editor?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, uniqueidentifier

I am automating a web page. One object doesn't have any unique identity. What should i use as its unique identifier, could you guys please suggest to me me something? This is a rich text editor. How would I enter my text into it?

When I use id (`ctl00_m_HelpDeskRequestRightColumn_ctl00_txtDetails`) as its identifier then it throws me an exception that `The expected element "<my object's name>" is not visible`

```html
<body class="ms-formbody" scroll="yes" style="border-top-width: medium;
    border-right-width: medium; border-bottom-width: medium;
    border-left-width: medium; border-top-style: none; border-right-style:
    none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none;
    background-color: white;" contentEditable="true" WebLocale="1033"
    BaseElementID="ctl00_m_HelpDeskRequestRightColumn_ctl00_txtDetails"
    wordWrap="false" ondragdrop="function anonymous() { RTE_OnDrop(this); }"
    RestrictedMode="true" AllowHyperlink="true" >
```

This is that object's inspected element description.

[Am writing my selenium webdriver script in java using eclipse.]

Comment: could you please provide the HTML snippet of the element that you are targetting?

Comment: Edited that. It didn't show in the first go

Comment: did you try to identify it using Xpath or CSS?

Comment: Please help me in the same, what'll be its corresponding xpath or cssSelector?

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath..

```
".//body[@BaseElementID='ctl00_m_HelpDeskRequestRightColumn_ctl00_txtDetails']"
```

Comment: Anything else that can help?

Comment: Is the element visible when you run this xpath?

Comment: What is the BaseElementID of the currently down element?

Comment: Is the BaseElementID dynamic?

Comment: currently down element, as in?

Comment: ctl00_m_HelpDeskRequestRightColumn_ctl00_txtDetails

Comment: Can you show me your line of code which uses this xpath?

Comment: //textarea[@id='ctl00_m_HelpDeskRequestRightColumn_ctl00_txtDetails']

Comment: Is that anywhere near what I have mentioned in the answer? Also I have asked for the complete line of code. If you can do that, we may proceed.

Comment: My comment didn't get through, yesterday. I tried with your said answer but it failed. so i used firepath and tried to decipher that. Also am using a framework, its tough to put all those LOCs here. Also its not the problem of code. It works for rest of the things.

Answer (score 0):

Id(s) are the safest to use so far I have learned. But from your question I can assume that your page may have some duplicate ids. Try the following to see if that works. Written in C#.

```
//this should find a collection of all elements having same ids     

var elements =Driver.FindElements(By.Id("ctl00_m_HelpDeskRequestRightColumn_ctl00_txtDetails"))

//looping through, find the element that is displayed and then send keys and break the loop
foreach (var element in elements )
{
    if (element.Displayed())
    {
        element.SendKeys("something");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the same, but still it tells me that " " element is not found :(

Comment: Now it tells me it has entered the text but it actually hasn't as in the text entered is not visible. So after clicking on submit button it gives an error on this editor box that its a required field and needs to be filled. So i've no clue where that text got entered

Comment: Okay I am assuming it needs more debugging. What I am assuming is you are not able to find the correct element. So do these: A. Use: *Driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("Your Xpath")).Count*; and if it returns more than one elements try using B. selenium IDE and see what selector it's using at least it would give you some idea.

Comment: Nothing seem to work, as it looked like IE driver/Webdriver isn't recognising this editor. As it was a form, i used the previous label and send out tab and then numbers to fill in that box. It's only feasible option right now with deadline is hanging close to my neck.

Comment: Have you tried _driver.switchto().frame("id")_ to set focus on the frame? I guess your issue is there.